# Extension of stay in Canada - no response and visa about to expire

Tags: visas, canada, visa-extensions

I have applied for an extension of stay in Canada, as I got married recently and the spousal application has been submitted. The thing is though, my application for extension of stay was sent in my mail/courier (due to issues with my computer) and, the time in the country (6 months) will expire in a few days.

I have not received any correspondence (via email or mail) saying that my application has been opened, however, I have received confirmation (via tracking) from the courier service that my package was delivered. What should I do now? I do not want to be illegal in the country.

Comment: Are you in Canada on a temporary residence (visitor) visa? Or some other visa? When does the actual visa expire?

Comment: Also what exactly does "spousal application" mean? Are you applying for permanent residence based on your marriage?

Comment: Should not be closed. It's not about immigration, it's about whether you can stay in Canada while applying for an extension for a visitor visa.

Comment: I got married while in Canada, on a Visitor's visa. We then applied for PR (though the spousal application)

Comment: Yes, a visitor can apply to extend their stay while PR is being processed. However, i was asking if after applying to extend my visa and there was no communication as yet from IRCC, what should I do as the time is going to expire soon. That's all!

Comment: I believe my answer explains that. Is there something in the answer you don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are in Canada on a temporary residence visa (visitor visa) then [the government pages say](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/extend-stay/after-apply.html):

> If you apply to extend your stay in Canada before the date you’re supposed to leave, you can legally remain in Canada until a decision is made on your application.

So you can stay until Canada decides to approve or not approve your visitor visa extension.

If your application to extend your stay is not approved then you need to leave Canada. Having a permanent residence application in progress does not grant you the right to stay in Canada. You should note that PR applications take a long time, and you may not be granted permission to stay the whole time until it is complete.

Comment: Am I being stupid, or do your last two sentences contradict the quote? The quote says they can stay; your last sentences say they can't and then that they might not be allowed. Sorry, I don't quite understand this.

Comment: If you apply for an extension to your visitor Visa you can stay until the decision is made. But applying for a PR doesn't get you the right to stay while it is being processed. So if the application for visitor Visa extension isn't approved you then need to leave. PR applications can take more than a year, and you probably won't get your visitor Visa extended that long.